# imagecreatefrompng() doesn't recognize the dynamic path

Tags: php, gd, gettype, imagecreatefrompng

I want to dynamically open a PNG image, but `imagecreatefrompng()` behaves oddly.
If I provide an explicit path like:

```
$our_image = imagecreatefrompng("https://example.com/customfiles/avatars/avatar2.png");
```

it works perfectly, but if I try to submit a string:

```
$our_image = imagecreatefrompng("https://example.com/customfiles/avatars/".$a);
```

it does not work. When I output the variable `$a` I see that it is equal to **avatar2.png**

Also, `gettype()` says that `$a` is a string.

- What could be the reason of this problem?
- Can it be something related to different type of strings?

Comment: please do a `var_dump($a);` - maybe there's an additional character you don't see when echoing (a space, a linefeed,..)?

Comment: _"it does not work"_ - do you get any errors? Or is `$our_image` justnull/false?

Comment: var_dump says that $a is a string(11) - exactly as it should be.

Comment: I do not get any errors. $our_image takes another image (named avatar1.png) in that folder. It shouldn't do this, as I output $a right before imagecreatefrompng line, and it is "avatar2.png", not "avatar1.png"

Comment: by "$our_image takes another image" you mean the output in your browser shows avatar1.png, right? Could it be a caching issue? How do you call that script? try appending a `?test=1234`

Comment: Since I cannot work with headers, I save the image to file and then open that file.
imagepng($our_image,"/home/example.com/customfiles/frontthumbs/testourimage.png");
echo '<img src="https://example.com/customfiles/frontthumbs/testourimage.png">';

The path in imagepng() is not through https, as if I indicate the path like that, I get warning " failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections "

Comment: could still be the browser getting the image from cache. try `echo '<img src="example.com/customfiles/frontthumbs/testourimage.png?test=1234">'` or just give it another name for a test.

Answer (score 0):

The file name change helped. It seems that the browser took the old file from cash.